# How to compare number in table and extract a text in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, numbers

[image]

So how to get some function to be automatic, I don't know how to use INDEX and MATCH to fill cell 7 to 19 with text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this in column N in the first blank cell under OPEL and copy it down in to the rest of the blanks.  if you get an error send a screenshot with the cell selected and include the formula bar at the top of the screen in your screenshot so i can verify the range.  someone else probably can do a shorter code, but this one will work for what you wanted.

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH($M15,F$9:F$28,0),0)>0,F$8,IF(IFERROR(MATCH($M15,G$9:G$28,0),0)>0,G$8,IF(IFERROR(MATCH($M15,H$9:H$28,0),0)>0,H$8,IF(IFERROR(MATCH($M15,I$9:I$28,0),0)>0,I$8))))
```